# gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull automatically ack?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

From the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/pubsub/subscriptions/pull) it doesn't state that the `--auto-ack` flag is automatically applied, and it have the inverse flag `--no-auto-ack`, so the default behavior is automatically ack or not?

context: I am doing pull using multiple command to dump the data as json line (to republish it to another project), something like this:

```
counter=0
for x in `seq 1 9`; do
    message=$(gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull subtopic1 \
      --limit 1000 \
      --format="value[separator='\n'](message.data)")
    if [ -z "$messages" ]
    then
        break
    fi
    counter=$((counter+1))
    echo $messages >> subtopic1__$x.jsonl
    echo -n "$counter "
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `gcloud pubsub subscription pull`, the default behavior is *not* to ack messages automatically. If you want to ack automatically messages, you must provide the `--auto-ack` flag. When `--auto-ack` is enabled, the table outputted with the messages has an `ACK_STATUS` column instead of an `ACK_ID` column.